# Android map activity crashing and I can't install APK

Tags: android, dictionary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.onsite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="@string/app_version" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />


    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="MainApplication" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Startup"
            android:theme="@style/SVSSplashTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my manifest. If I remove  `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` I can install export APK and install it in the device but my android map Activity crashing. If I add this line I can't install APK. I am not getting the Application installed. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove what? please provide details

Comment: remove <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: sorrry i am very new to Stack OverFlow..

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess without seeing the logcat, but probably you are trying to install onto a device which lacks the libraries implementing the maps api.

If this is a physical device you are out of luck - your vendor did not license this proprietary component from Google. (you could check how supported open street map is on Android?)

If it is the emulator, you need to switch to an AVD based on one of the "Google APIs" images.

Comment: can you explain what is the difference between openStreet Map view and ordinary map view please.

Comment: It is a different product from a different outfit with different licensing.  I do not know how well it is supported on Android or if its maps would be suitable - was just putting it out there as an idea you could look in to if Google's maps are not available on your target device.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your consol if it is giving the error like,missing shared library,then launch a new emulator with android Google API 2.2 or whatever OS you are using,then your map application work perfectly.